# Make sure BERT model does not load pretrained weights?

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I want to make sure my BertModel does not loads pre-trained weights. I am using auto class (hugging face) which loads model automatically.

My question is how do I load bert model without pretrained weights?

Comment: Please post the code with which you are currently initializing your model.

Comment: @dennlinger that's what I want buddy.

Comment: I was referring to your comment `I am using auto class (hugging face) which loads model automatically.`, which indicates that you already had some existing code/attempt. Seems like the question got solved in the meantime anyways...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AutoConfig instead of AutoModel:

```
from transformers import AutoConfig
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model =  AutoModel.from_config(config)
```

this should set up the model without loading the weights.

[Documentation here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/auto.html?highlight=from_pretrained#transformers.AutoConfig.from_pretrained) [and here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/models/auto/modeling_auto.html#AutoModel.from_config)

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight https://stackoverflow.com/users/6664872/cronoik !

Comment: For me, this still loads the weights from the pretrained model (transformers v2.11)

Answer (score 1):

You can re-initialize of a `PreTrainedModel` class with `init_weights` method [(Huggingface Documentation)](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.init_weights), if the model is already loaded with pre-trained weights.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just load the model with pretrained weights, iterate over model parameters and set the model parameters randomly with whatever initialization technique you prefer.